# Slideshare API 500 response for upload slideshow (www.slideshare.net/api/2/upload_slideshow)

Tags: php, api, integration, linkedin-api, slideshow

Since yesterday slideshare API for upload slideshow using PHP didn't work.
We receive only 500 response (check below).

We accessed endpoint: https://www.slideshare.net/api/2/upload_slideshow

```
  <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">

  <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
    <link href="/stylesheets/error.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen" />

    <script type="text/javascript">
      function disableSearch(event) {
        var t = document.getElementById('searchstring');
        if(t.value === 'Type text here …' || t.value.length === 0) {
          event.preventDefault();
        }
      }
    </script>
    <title>500 error. The page could not be loaded.</title>

  </head>

  <body>
    <div class="smiley"><img src="/images/errorsmiley.png" width="128px" height="128px" alt="error" /></div>
    <div class="errorBox">
      <p class="errorCode">500</p>
      <h1>Sorry! The page could not be loaded.</h1>
      <h2> 
      This is probably a temporary error. Just refresh the page and retry. If problem continues, please check back in 5-10 minutes.
        <br/><br/>You could also check out our <a href="/">homepage</a> or search below.</h2>
        <div class="searchSection">
          <form style="display: inline;" action="/search/slideshow" method="get">
          <input type="text" id="searchstring" name="q" value="Type text here &hellip;" class="errorSearchBox" onclick="this.value = '';">
          <button type="submit" onclick="disableSearch(event)">
            Search<span>&nbsp;</span></button>
          </form>
        </div>
    </div>
  </body>
  </html>
```

Comment: Weird that such an API would answer with an HTML document, instead of just an error code in whatever data format is normally used. But anyway, if your code worked before and now suddenly this error occurs, then you should perhaps talk to the people providing this API first.

Comment: Hi CBroe, this code stop works 2 days ago. Until there works fine to me. I received instructions from Linkedin people to add this situation here (error) tagging my question with **Linkedin**. I hope engineers see that and fix it!

Comment: Hello. Did you find an answer? Looks like they removed description of this API call from documentation without any warning. And sadly ignoring in all channels (stackoverflow, google group, linkedin support)

Comment: @SergeyZherevchuk too much strange. No answer until this moment.

Comment: @SergeyZherevchuk study change service for Google Slides or other similar service. That's situation unacceptable to me and all other people using Slideshare. Before acquisition Slideshare works well.

Comment: @SergeyZherevchuk did you use this API ?

Comment: @ViniciusCâmara, I did. I tried to chat with there support twice, finally they said that provided support for slideshare api only available on developers page. API call disappeared from docs, so I decided it's permanent. Sad to say, I don't know alternatives to this service.

Comment: @SergeyZherevchuk I research entire Internet for service like this. Don't exists!

Comment: @SergeyZherevchuk I will create a new one for my company. Contract service for conversion file e after conversion create embed. Any other idea ?